# xaml desing issue with ZeroProximity.Accordian for window store app

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, accordion

I have the following MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="ComponentGuidTestUW8.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ComponentGuidTestUW8"
xmlns:controls="using:ZeroProximity.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <controls:Accordion>
        <controls:AccordionItem Header="Heading 1">
            <controls:AccordionItem.Content>
                <TextBlock Text="Texting"/>
            </controls:AccordionItem.Content>
        </controls:AccordionItem>
    </controls:Accordion>
</Grid>
```

The page does display the Accordion control properly when I run the app but I am getting the following error when I try to design xaml file in VS 2015:

> "COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a
>   COM component."

[Desing Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lZ9y.png)

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with the control: have you try to contact the author ?

Comment: I think I will add the control using C# code as the code works.

Comment: Yes but you won't be able to get a Design Time preview if you add the control using C#